# Jquery mobile AJAX request to external JSON data fails

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, asp-classic

I am trying to develop a mobile application using JQUERY mobile. For its data, my app needs to accesses an existing service that returns a JSON object.

```
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://pruebanico.comze.com/prueba2.json',     
            dataType: 'text',    
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback', 
            timeout: 5000,     
            success: function(json, status){

            alert (json);
            });
```

When executing this piece of code, an undefined error is displayed.

Having a closer look at the result of the returned page in Firebug, it seems to be that everything is OK json-wise

```
 {"totalResultsCount":0,"geonames":[]}
```

What can be the problem of the undefined error?

Comment: You could always treat the returned XML as a DOM or jQuery object and use `$.children()` _et al_ to find the node you're looking for.

Comment: If you treat it as DOM depending the browser it will strip some tags much likely `<html/>`, `<head/>` and `<body/>`. A cross-browser way won't be straightforward.

Comment: Correct your question if it doesn't illustrate your issue. It is useless.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I updated title and question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you've got a syntax error. You haven't closed the same amount of parentheses/braces as you opened. It should be this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://pruebanico.comze.com/prueba2.json',
    dataType: 'text',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(json, status) {
        alert(json);
    }
});​
```

The second problem seems to be that your server doesn't return `JSONP` but just plain `JSON`, which results in a cross-origin exception.

You need to fix your server code to instead return something like

```
jsoncallback({"totalResultsCount":0,"geonames":[]})
```

**OR**

Implement CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) on your server, but note that the current releases of Opera and Internet Explorer don't yet support the standard version of CORS. (IE has its own [`XDomainRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object but it's different to the CORS standard. The next release of both browsers will ship with standard CORS support though.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is indeed a CORS problem.